# MS CRM Lookup field UI is messed up with custom filter

Tags: user-interface, lookup, dynamics-crm-2013

I have added a lookup field on one of the forms in CRM. I have filled it with 
custom view using addCustomView() method. When I open the form the lookup looks normal as it should be.

But when I select something from the lookup it shrinks and looks like this.
[image]

When I comment the addCustomView() code. The lookup works as it is.
Does anyone have any idea about this behavior ? I am using Google Chrome V40+.

Comment: Does it works on other browsers? Can you post the code?

Comment: I have added custom view to that lookup field. on other browsers same behavior is seen.

Comment: I resolved this by setting the IsDefaultView to false in addCustomView() method.